# Database number of columns and separate table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using MySQL database and wondering about the database table designs.

I see sets of two kinds of tables designed by an experience PHP developer. Basically one table contains some dynamic stats and the other table more static ones but each record would have the same row_id. For example, a user table where info like name, pass are stored and a user_stats table where like a summary of actions maybe like the total money spent, etc.

Is there any real advantage in doing this besides adding more clarity to the functions of each table. How many columns would you say is optimal in a table? Is it bad to mix the more static info and dynamic stuff together into like 20 columns of the same table?

Comment: Often this is just due to history. If you have a large table, it can be inconvenient to add new columns to it, so you add a new table for a new application. You can also use this method to enforce access control: different users can update different tables.

Comment: inconvenient as in doing an `alter` locks the table while mysql rebuilds it with the new column. if you have a "large" table and/or it's serving a live site, that lock can/will kill the site. adding new columns into a new table and joining together gets around that.

Comment: Some does not want a user to be updated, when only stats will be changed. Duo to security, logging, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From a design standpoint, you might consider that the `User` table describes **things,** namely "users."  There might be hundreds of thousands of them, and rows might need to remain in that table ... even for Users who've been pushing-up daisies in the local graveyard for many years now ... because this table associates the `user_id` values that are scattered throughout the database with individual *properties* of that "thing."

Meanwhile, we also collect `User_Stats`.  But, we don't keep these stats nearly so long, and we don't keep them about every `User` that we know of. *(Certainly not about the ones who live in the graveyard.)* And, when we want to run reports about those statistics, we don't want to pore through all of those hundreds-of-thousands of `User` records, looking for the ones that actually *have* statistics.

`User_Stats`, then, is an entirely separate collection of records.  Yes, it is *related to* `Users`, *e.g.* in the referential-integrity sense that "any `user_id` *(foreign key ...)* in `User_Stats` must correspond to a `user_id` in `Users`. But it is, nevertheless, "an entirely separate collection of records."

Another important reason for keeping these as a separate table is that there might naturally be a **one-to-many relationship** between a `User` and his `User_Stats`. (For instance, maybe you keep aggregate statistics by day, week, or month ...)

If you have nothing better to do with your afternoon than to read database textbooks ... **;-)** ... the formal name of this general topic is:  **"normal forms."** ("First," "Second," "Third," and so on.)